# Retain the highest absolute value and return an average value from rows with duplicate index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a set of values with duplicate index in a DataFrame:

```
         value
CDE   2.318620
CDE  -3.097715
LXU  -3.791043
LXU   4.818995
SWN   3.059964
SWN  -4.349304
OAS  -3.336539
LPI  -3.037097
LPI  -5.701044
LPI  -3.519923
CZR  -3.270018
CZR  -3.056712
```

The required result is to retain only the highest absolute values and return the average values in a new column:

```
         value    average
CDE  -3.097715  -0.389547
LXU   4.818995   0.513976
SWN  -4.349304  -0.644670
OAS  -3.336539  -3.336539
LPI  -5.701044  -4.086021
CZR  -3.270018  -3.163365
```

I have tried to .apply(lambda) to the duplicate rows but got an "axis" error:

```
max_absolute = lambda x: max(x.min(), x.max(), key=abs)
df_duplicate_absmax = df.groupby(df.index).apply(max_absolute, axis=1)
```

ps: Adapting Abhi's solution to work with NaN:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index)['value'].agg([lambda x: max(x[~np.isnan(x)], key=abs), 'mean'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index)['value'].agg([lambda x: max(x,key=abs), 'mean'])

df1.columns = ['value', 'average']

print (df1)

        value   average
CDE -3.097715 -0.389547
CZR -3.270018 -3.163365
LPI -5.701044 -4.086021
LXU  4.818995  0.513976
OAS -3.336539 -3.336539
SWN -4.349304 -0.644670
```

Comment: There are two reasons why this solution is inefficient: (1) using pure Python built-ins (`max`) with Pandas series / NumPy arrays, (2) using `groupby` twice when a single `groupby` is sufficient.

Comment: Good solution, Abhi with thanks :) I appreciate the use of max_absolute lambda function for simplicity!

Comment: Nice!. Note that columns can be named directly in .agg like `.agg([('value', lambda x: max(x,key=abs)), ('average', 'mean')])`

Comment: Excellent, Andrew Lavers for adding value to a good solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `groupby` + `agg` with two functions, one to calculate the maximum by absolute value, the other to calculate the mean:

```
def max_abs(x):
    return x.iloc[x.abs().values.argmax()]

res = df.groupby(level=0).agg([max_abs, 'mean'])\
        .xs('value', axis=1, drop_level=True)

print(res)

      max_abs      mean
CDE -3.097715 -0.389547
CZR -3.270018 -3.163365
LPI -5.701044 -4.086021
LXU  4.818995  0.513976
OAS -3.336539 -3.336539
SWN -4.349304 -0.644670
```

Comment: That's great, jpp - very Pythonic!

Comment: I also like your use of .xs() and the MultiIndex address, jpp :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
cod      value
CDE   2.318620
CDE  -3.097715
LXU  -3.791043
LXU   4.818995
SWN   3.059964
SWN  -4.349304
OAS  -3.336539
LPI  -3.037097
LPI  -5.701044
LPI  -3.519923
CZR  -3.270018
CZR  -3.056712
"""), header=1, Index=None)

# Create a new column with absoulte value
df['abs_value'] = df['value'].abs()

# Calulate the mean in new data farame, grouped by code using
# pandas groupped aggregation naming the column average
df_avg = df.groupby("cod").value.agg([('average', 'mean')])

# Choose the row within group with largest abs value
df_abs = df.sort_values("abs_value").groupby("cod").tail(1)[["cod", "value"]]

# Join the average and the max
df_abs.join(df_avg, on="cod")
```

Result:

```
    cod     value   average
1   CDE -3.097715 -0.389547
10  CZR -3.270018 -3.163365
6   OAS -3.336539 -3.336539
5   SWN -4.349304 -0.644670
3   LXU  4.818995  0.513976
8   LPI -5.701044 -4.086021
```